# Connection to MYSQL Database Using JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to connect to a new database using JDBC for a project I am working on which will allow me to output a whole load of statistics on sports game. But I am running into some trouble whilst trying to connect to the database. I receive the following error below.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due      to underlying exception: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.net.ConnectException
MESSAGE: Connection refused

STACKTRACE:

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:244)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:256)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:271)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2771)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at JDBC.main(JDBC.java:22)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **



Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2847)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at JDBC.main(JDBC.java:22)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

This error is produced from my code which is as followed:

```
//STEP 1. Import required packages
import java.sql.*;

public class JDBC {
    // JDBC driver name and database URL
    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/";

    //  Database credentials
    static final String USER = "username";
    static final String PASS = "password";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try{
            //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            //STEP 3: Open a connection
            System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

            //STEP 4: Execute a query
            System.out.println("Creating database...");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();

            String sql = "CREATE DATABASE PREDICTOR";
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            System.out.println("Database created successfully...");
        }catch(SQLException se){
            //Handle errors for JDBC
            se.printStackTrace();
        }catch(Exception e){
            //Handle errors for Class.forName
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            //finally block used to close resources
            try{
                if(stmt!=null)
                    stmt.close();
            }catch(SQLException se2){
            }// nothing we can do
            try{
                if(conn!=null)
                    conn.close();
            }catch(SQLException se){
                se.printStackTrace();
            }//end finally try
        }//end try
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    }//end main
}
```

I have disabled my firewall and looked on previous posts on stack overflow trying to amend my problem but alas connection is being refused. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Connection refused is pretty self explanatory. The server isn't running or it isn't listening on that host:port

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect Java to a MySQL database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/connect-java-to-a-mysql-database)

Answer (score 0):

> Connection refused

This means that the TCP communication to the server was actively rejected - this was done at the TCP layer, the connection never made it to your service - your code is irrelevant at this point.

This can be caused by a few different issues:

- The SQL server is not actually running
- There is a firewall in place blocking the connections
- You are connecting to a different port than the server is listening to.

Answer (score 0):

I think your SQL server is not running .
Please check the server status.
or You should reinstall the server. It may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your  DB_URL is incorrect. It should

```
DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/databaseName";
```

or you can also use port number in your url if the database server is not using the default port

```
DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:portNumber/databaseName";
```

For detail information please visit [this site](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html)